# Customize Layout templates In MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I known There is a default _Layout.cshtml file in Asp.net MVC just like MasterPage in Asp.net Web Site. Can I define multiple layout templates in my MVC app? If so ,How to make it? Please give me some code example . Thanks.

Comment: Did you [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nesting%20of%20layouts%20in%20mvc%203%20) ??

Comment: No, Next time i will google first . thanks . And Shyju just gave me the best answer I have got. Thanks .I didn't found it exactly Even if I had looked through some tutorial from [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple Layout pages and use it in differnt views. You may mention the new layout pages inside your views by mentioning the Layout property in your views.

Create a new `View` and name it as `_AdminLayout.cshtml` under `Views/Shared` folder. You may create your HTML markup for your master page template there. Make sure you have   `@RenderBody()` section in your Layout page so that the content of your normal views will be replaced here when it renders.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>My new Layout</h1>
      @RenderBody()
  </body>
</html>
```

And if you want to use this Layout in a view, you can do it like this

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
<p>The content here will be present inside the render body section of layout</p>
```

If you want to use the new Layout for all the Views by default without explicitly mentioning like the above code, you can do it in the `Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` file

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
```